# How to replace values in a dataset with another values in the same dataset in R?

Tags: r, replace, import, dataset, data-cleaning

Suppose I have the following Dataset called `D`:

```
D <- read.csv("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B5V8AyEFBTmXQ1QwWVZuS3FXOHc&export=download")
```

In `D`, whenever the ***below condition*** is met, I want `D$n1` to be replaced with `D$N`.  How can I do this in *BASE R*?

```
if(D$t.type == 0 & is.na(D$n1) & is.na(D$n2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
D$n1[(D$t.type == 0 & is.na(D$n1) & is.na(D$n2))]=D$N[(D$t.type == 0 & is.na(D$n1) & is.na(D$n2))]
```

Comment: I would rather build a new csv instead.